# What does dian gui bu mean?

Tags: classical-chinese, traditional-characters

I've tracked 點鬼簿 as far as 張鷟《朝野僉載》. I thought it was something like 'augmenting the records of the dead', but I don't really understand it?

Comment: Japanese "Tenkibo [A Family Resister（sic） of Deaths]" written by Akutagawa Ryunosuke http://ci.nii.ac.jp/naid/110006199609

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's a derogatory word.
2. It's used to mock poems which abused name of the ancients and historical stories.

Comment: Could you add a little about why these words are used that way?  The comment by user6065 says it is the title of a specific work.

Comment: why not supply examples from the literature (examples on the web) for confirmation

Comment: Literally, "點鬼" means call the dead name, ”簿“  book, directory;

As you see, the literal meaning of "點鬼簿" is records of the dead. it is used to describe a poet who like to use name of the ancients,  such as "杨炯(yang jiong)" See the Wiki:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang_Jiong. Actually, the origin of it because yang jiong.